# How to get the second pair value from vector pair container?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I want to get the second value of the pair using the first value in a vector pair container. How can I find and traverse in the vector pair and get the value of second pair value using first value pair?

In the code the "G.keys()" is a vector pair which the first value is char and the next is a string.

```
void search_shortest_path(){
    Graph<T> G = create_graph();
    T source;
    T destination;
    std::cout<<"AVAILABLE ROUTES\n";

    for(auto k: G.keys()){
        std::cout<<k.first<<". "<<k.second<<"\n";
    }

    std::cout<<"Enter your starting point: ";
    std::cin>>source;
    std::cout<<"Enter your destination point: ";
    std::cin>>destination;

    //GET SECOND PAIR VALUE USING SOURCE AND DESTINATION ?
    

    G.dijkstra_algorithm(source, destination);
    }
```

Comment: unclear, your code is not complete (you mention a char and a string, but I see `T`)? Please post an [mre].

Comment: Can you use `std::find` or `std::find_if`?

Answer (score 0):

use `std::map` instead then you can find any element associated with its key `iterator find (const key_type& k)`  [std::map::find](http://%20https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/)

Comment: Sure, but maybe the OP has a constraint on the input container and it cannot change it.

Comment: thank you!, I already convert it and It is more easy than using pair!